# Best practices to imperatively invoke GET requests (with caching) in react-query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I am building a React component for typeahead address search, which uses a cloud service to fetch potential address matches. When a user selects an address from the dropdown, I need to make another network call to retrieve additional details (like coordinates) for that address. After fetching these details, I want to trigger an onSelect callback prop to notify the parent component.

**Requirements**:

1. Invoke onSelect exactly once for each user selection.
2. Cache the results of the network calls, as there's no need to invalidate the cache.

**Options Considered**:

1. Using await retrieve() in Event Handler: This approach doesn't offer caching. I would need to manage the cache manually, perhaps using useState. It also doesn't handle scenarios like component unmounting during an ongoing request.
2. Using useQuery from TanStack: I considered using its onSuccess callback to trigger onSelect. However, onSuccess may not fire if the data is already cached. Additionally, ensuring that the query runs exactly once seems challenging. I might have to use refetch(), which feels like overkill.
3. Using queryClient.fetchQuery: This could be an alternative to useQuery, with a staleTime set to Infinity to ensure caching.

**Question**:

What is the most effective and readable pattern to achieve these requirements? I'm looking for a solution that is easy to implement, easy to read, and adheres to the specified requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's number 3: `queryClient.fetchQuery` with a `staleTime` set to `Infinity`. Alternatively, you can use `queryClient.ensureQueryData`, which will only fetch if there isn't data in the cache.

You can await calls to that method and then invoke the onSuccess callback.

Note that without `useQuery`, you have no observer, so your Query is eligible for garbage collection, which means data will be removed after the default of 5 minutes. You can set a higher `cacheTime` (v4 - it's `gcTime` in v5).